# How to install prerequisites using msi file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-installer, prerequisites

i have create a vb.net project for this project i have create setup project ,when i create the setup it create two files those are **Setup.exe** and **Myproject.msi**.In this project i want run the prerequisites (when target machine doesn't have sqlserver2008R2 then it will install otherwise  it leave it) .If i run the setup file it will install all prerequisites but  my client wants only **msi** file.So please help me how to integrate or run the setup file with  msi file .
          Please help me.....

I have goggled many  sites but did not get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not easy way, because you can't install one msi from another, if you don't have Windows Installer 4.5 (installed by default only from Windows 7). The simpler and proper way in this case will be create bootstrapped setup.exe and add MSSQLServer2008r2 as prerequisite.
More about installing one msi from another could find here with help of search "Chained MSI"

Comment: Hi thank you for your replay .i have create bootstrapped setup.exe it call all prerequisite(what i selected),When i run the setup.exe it will install prerequisites ok fine.But,in my case i want run the prerequisite with msi installer means i don't want run the setup.exe.I ma using windows7 and i have windows installer 4.5 and 3.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't explain it in easy way. I only could recommend you find information about Chained MSI.